# Как в html сначала изменить элемент в js, а потом его отобразить?

Tags: javascript, html, css, веб-программирование, frontend

У меня есть два варианта бокового меню, которые меняются в зависимости от определённого условия следующим образом:

```html
<div class="sidebar">...</div>
<div class="alt-sidebar">...</div>
<script>
window.onload = function () {
  if(getCookie("alt_sidebar") === "true"){
    show_sidebar();
    hide_alt_sidebar();
  }else{
    hide_sidebar();
    show_alt_sidebar();
  }
}
```

Им задаются значения значения display none и flex. Однако во время загрузки страницы на кадр показывается их стандартное состояние, а после уже меняется. Т.е. если сначала был активен sidebar и неактивен alt-sidebar, а после загрузки их значение нужно поменять, то на кадр происходит рендер не нужной картинке, что мешает пользователю.

Как сделать, чтобы js сначала менял значения элементов, а уже позже происходил рендер страницы?

Comment: Может сделать их display:none по умолчанию?

Comment: тогда на 1 кадр отображается всё без сайдбара